# Возвращение колличества дней в месяце года в вычисляемом поле SQL Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, дата

Загружаю файл DBF с отфильтрованными полями через ADOQuery посредством OpenDialog:

```
  ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="' +AppFolderPath1 + '";Extended Properties="DBASE IV;";"';
  ADOConnection1.LoginPrompt:=false;
  ADOConnection1.Mode:=cmReadWrite;
  ADOConnection1.Connected:=true;

  ADOQuery1.Active:=false;
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Clear;

  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT NC, '+'''01.'''+'+mid(ltrim(str(dot)),5,2)+'+'''.'''+'+mid(ltrim(str(dot)),1,4) AS data, GOR, QN, QBT FROM ');
  ADOQuery1.SQL.Add( AppFileName1);
  ADOQuery1.Open;
```

Функция `'+'''01.'''+'+mid(ltrim(str(dot)),5,2)+'+'''.'''+'+mid(ltrim(str(dot)),1,4)` - преобразует дату из формата "021987" в "01.02.1987"(необходимо для последующей выгрузки в файл.

Теперь собственно вопрос. У меня есть вычисляемое поле "Qoil", которое я не могу никак организовать, потому что не знаю, как возвратить количество дней из получившегося поля "date"(с учетом високосного года). Знаю, что есть ф-я `DaysInAMonth, но как применить ее в SQL-запросе нигде не нашел. От незнания пробовал так, но пишет ошибку при выполнении, что пропущен оператор в синтаксисе:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT NC, '+'''01.'''+'+mid(ltrim(str(dot)),5,2)+'+'''.'''+'+mid(ltrim(str(dot)),1,4) AS data, GOR, QN/(DaysInAMonth(((mid(ltrim(str(dot)),1,4),mid(ltrim(str(dot)),5,2))) AS Qoil, QBT FROM ');
```

Comment: Я бы сделал его вычислимым полем dataset-а, А в SQL запросе запрашивал бы исходные величины: qn, dot и что там ещё надо?

Comment: Правила несложные. Можно одним CASE все решить.

Comment: Мне в принципе так и надо. Просто не знаю как это прописать: Поле Qoil=поле Qn/значение Edit*количество дней месяца поля Dot...

Answer (score 1):

Вы смешиваете Delphi и SQL в одну кучу, поэтому и не работает.

В Delphi функция `DaysInAMonth` возвращает число дней в месяце.

В SQL для этого готовой функции нет, есть способ

```
DAY(DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(MM,DATEDIFF(MM,-1,@DATE),0)))
```

Comment: Но в SQL такого тоже нет. Вы наверное имели в виду SQL Server?